# Copy key to value for all empty non-array elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, key

I have an associative multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    7 => [49 => null, 41 => null],
    8 => [70 => null, 69 => null],
    105 => null,
    9 => null,
    10 => null
]
```

Now, I need to work with each key, but I am struggling to access all elements through a `foreach()` loop -- because there are no values. I have been trying to use `array_keys()`, but that is not suitable for multidimensional keys.

Is there a way I can assign the keys as the values to have a structure like this?

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [49] => 49
            [41] => 41
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [70] => 70
            [69] => 69
        )

    [105] => 105
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
)
```

This way I could use a `foreach()` to get the values of each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use array_walk_recursive in this case. In the callback function of array_walk_recursive if we pass the element reference then inside the callback function we can change the empty value with key.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!$item && $key) $item  = $key;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to assign the key as value to each entry whose value is not an array.

Comment: The callback receives the key as an argument, but it doesn't receive the array, so how will it know which subarray to assign the value to?

Comment: @barmar if we pass the element reference and change the value inside callback function then it will be fine.

Comment: @BerozaPaul I see that in your answer. This answer didn't mention that detail, and it's not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

From PHP7.4, you can enjoy the brevity of "arrow function" syntax.  You still need to make the leafnode's value modifiable by reference and manually assign `$k`'s value to `$v`.  The arrow function syntax attempts (by default) to `return` the value in the expression, but the return value is ignored.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X9VA6))

```
$array = [
    7 => [49 => null, 41 => null],
    8 => [70 => null, 69 => null],
    105 => null,
    9 => null,
    10 => null
];

array_walk_recursive($array, fn(&$v, $k) => $v = $k);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  7 => 
  array (
    49 => 49,
    41 => 41,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    70 => 70,
    69 => 69,
  ),
  105 => 105,
  9 => 9,
  10 => 10,
)
```